# Cannot pass variable from kickstart to rpm

Tags: rpm, kickstart

I have a common package that need's to be installed into different servers. The installation is done through the same kickstart template file. So the kickstart template is used to produce the kickstart for every server and then is executed into different servers and the same package is installed into this servers. In this package I need to create the ssh keys (which I manage to do correctly and in the comment part of the key-gen I want to pass a variable that will be different for every server.) So how I think it should be done is to create a variable in this template files and then pass this variable to the spec file. So:

In the kickstart template I do:

```
svr_name=<xsl:value-of select="$node"/>
 
packages=("svr_xxxxxxx_common"
           "svr_common"
)
```

which will be different for every instance of kickstart. And inside of one of the packages I do in the %post phase:

`ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -f /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa -C "${svr_name}" -N  ""`

But this does not work. This variable is shown as not existing after installation. The ssh-keygen works fine but without comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment is sanitized by rpm before executing the scriptlet.

You can use files. E.g., in kickstart:

```
%pre
echo "svr_XXX" > /foo
```

and then in `%post` scriptlet of rpm.

```
%post
SVR_NAME=$(cat /foo)
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -f /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa -C "${SVR_NAME}" -N  ""
```

Handling the (non)existence of the file and better location for that file should be done too. I will leave it to you :)

Comment: I thought to do it that way but I put extra dependencies in the rpm and I wouldn't want to do so. But anyway thank you